# iOS objC upload file to firebase not happening

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I need to upload a file to firebase, firebase account is set, iOS project is connecting...

The file exists, and I check for file size before sending...

when I try the upload the process starts, but I get the error:

> > > Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

This is the path for the file:

> > > /var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/A14B0460-06E7-4EC0-80CE-9C27B5B70BC2/Documents/img.JPG

My doubt is if I have "riversRef" property correctly set?... What is missing?

```
- (void)uploadFileTest:(NSURL*)url {
// reference
FIRStorage * storage = [FIRStorage storage];

// Create a root reference
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage reference];
FIRStorageReference *riversRef = [storageRef child:@"images/rios.jpg"]; // is this correct?
FIRStorageMetadata *metadata = [[FIRStorageMetadata alloc] init];
metadata.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

NSLog(@"storageRef: %@", storageRef);
NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
NSLog(@"metadata : %@", metadata);

//object size?
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){
  long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:url.absoluteString error:nil][NSFileSize] longLongValue];
  NSLog(@"sik: %lld", fileSize);
}else{
  NSLog(@"nanais");
}

NSURL *curaul = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[url path]];

// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/rios.jpg'
FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [riversRef putFile:curaul metadata:metadata];

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusResume handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Upload resumed, also fires when the upload starts
  NSLog(@"upload started");
}];

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusPause handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Upload paused
  NSLog(@"paused");
}];

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusProgress handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Upload reported progress
  double percentComplete = 100.0 * (snapshot.progress.completedUnitCount) / (snapshot.progress.totalUnitCount);
  NSLog(@"percentComplete :: %f", percentComplete);
}];

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusSuccess handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Upload completed successfully
  NSLog(@"successfully");
}];

// Errors only occur in the "Failure" case
[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusFailure handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"errore :: %@", snapshot.error.description);

  if (snapshot.error != nil) {

    switch (snapshot.error.code) {
      case FIRStorageErrorCodeObjectNotFound:
        // File doesn't exist
        break;
      case FIRStorageErrorCodeUnauthorized:
        // User doesn't have permission to access file
        break;
      case FIRStorageErrorCodeCancelled:
        // User canceled the upload
        break;
        /* ... */
      case FIRStorageErrorCodeUnknown:
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
        break;
    }
  }
}];
}
```

Is the response to unknown error?

How to fix upload?, thanks